# ActiveRecord "select" results of model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails app that pulls in music from Soundcloud. This data contains a title, which I save as `mix.sc_title` but it's not always properly formatted. I have added an additional attribute on my Mix model which I call `mix.override_title`

For display on my site, I want to use the override title if available, and the sc_title in all other cases.

I have a Mix model method to do this for me

```
def display_title
    override_title.blank? sc_title : override_title
end
```

Mixes#index grabs `@mixes = Mix.where(:active => true)` and mixes/index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<ul>
<% @mixes.each do |mix| %>
    <li><%= link_to mix.display_title, mix %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

As you can see, I'm not directly using any mix attributes, and so I take a huge hit when I go to the DB, and I don't actually benefit from it.

Is there a leaner way to get just the information I need? (`mix.display_title`)

I have tried `Mix.select("display_title").where(:active => true)` but it fails because display_title is not a real DB column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `Mix.select("sc_title, override_title").where(:active => true)` and it will work, since those are the actual fields that the method uses.  I don't really think getting the additional attributes gives you *that* much of a DB hit but sometimes selecting only what you need can be beneficial.

As you start chaining on more `Arel` commands, consider putting the select into a model method:

```
def select_active_titles
  select("sc_title, override_title").where(:active => true)
end
```

Edit:  Your `link_to` helper also secretly calls `mix.id` to link to the right mix, so make sure it's working and if not add id to the list of selected attributes.